# Unknown format code 'r' for object of type 'bool'

Tags: python, string-formatting

This works:

```
In [3]: print "%r"%(1==2)
False
```

This sort of works:

```
In [2]: formatted_str = "{0:1.2f}".format(1==2)

In [3]: formatted_str
Out[3]: '0.00'
```

However:

```
In [5]: formatted_str = "{0:r}".format(1==2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-b136410cc311> in <module>()
----> 1 formatted_str = "{0:r}".format(1==2)

ValueError: Unknown format code 'r' for object of type 'bool'
```

How do you make `.format()` to print "True" or "False" for bool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first:

> How do you make .format() to print "True" or "False" for bool?

Just don't specify anything. The default formatting for bool values already gives you `'True'` or `'False'`. And the same is true for `%`-formatting:

```
>>> '{0}'.format(False)
'False'
>>> '%s' % (False,)
'False'
```

The `__format__`, `__str__`, and `__repr__` for `bool` all return the same thing—in 2.x, the `__unicode__` returns a Unicode version of the same thing too, of course. Which also means:

```
>>> format(False), format(False, ''), repr(False), str(False), unicode(False)
('False', 'False', 'False', 'False', u'False')
```

---

But more generally, if you *did* need the `%r`, how would you do that with `format`?

Well, there is no such *format spec code* (the thing that comes after the `:`) as `r`, but there's a *conversion modifier flag* `r` (the thing that after the `!` separator, and before the `:`, if present). So:

```
'{0!r}'.format(1==2)
```

The docs for [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) explain in more detail:

> The conversion field causes a type coercion before formatting. Normally, the job of formatting a value is done by the `__format__()` method of the value itself. However, in some cases it is desirable to force a type to be formatted as a string, overriding its own definition of formatting. By converting the value to a string before calling `__format__()`, the normal formatting logic is bypassed.
>
> Three conversion flags are currently supported: `'!s'` which calls `str()` on the value, `'!r'` which calls `repr()` and `'!a'` which calls `ascii()`.

Note that this also means that the basic `'{0}'.format(1==2)` is not actually doing the same thing as `'%s' % (1=2,)`, because it's calling `__format__` rather than `__str__`.

More generally, while many of the format spec codes match format conversion type codes for `%`-formatting, it's not an exact match. Besides splitting the idea of "conversion type" into two separate things, there are also codes that do subtly or radically different things—most obviously, `'%%'` means "This isn't a format code, it's a literal `%`", while `':%'` means "Print this as a percentage". When it isn't obvious, the docs are always clear.

Comment: This is a very good answer.  I like how you highlighted the conversion modifier flag and explained that `!` is a _separator_.  I feel like you've formalized my understanding of the format mini language better than I could have before I read this answer.  +1 from me.

Comment: @mgilson: Have I got the right terms for all these pieces? I have no problem remembering how to use them, but remembering what to call them is another story…

Comment: No idea :) -- they might not even have names (before now).  I use the "conversion modifier flag" so infrequently that I need to look it up every time I want it...

Comment: @mgilson: I do forget about `!s`, because how often do you run into something whose `__format__('')` returns something different and it's not what you want? But I use `!r` all the time with exceptions, and used to use `!a` for some reason (maybe printing the offending string in `UnicodeError` exceptions before 3.3? I forget…).

Comment: Had forgotten that `u'Something'` meant unicode. Also `'{0!a}'.format(1==2)` returns a `ValueError` in `2.7`, 'False' in `3.4.1`.

Comment: @MikeLL: IIRC, !a was added in 3.1 and not backported to 2.x (even with Unicode format strings). Anyway, 3.0-3.2 could sometimes raise a UnicodeError that would then raise a new UnicodeError if you tried to print/log it; !a was a convenient way to get something ASCII friendly no matter what.. At least I think so, it's been a while.

Answer (score 2):

Like this (python2.7+):

```
>>> '{!r}'.format(1 == 2)
'False'
```

Or, if you want to specify the position (or are forced to be compatible with python2.6):

```
>>> '{1!r} is not {0!r}'.format(1==2, 1==1)
'True is not False'
```

You can even use keywords as normal:

```
>>> '{foo!r} is not {0!r}'.format(1==2, foo=1==1)
'True is not False'
```